# Precargar Playlist

Tags: html5, audio

Tengo un array de `url` que debo de reproducir en `audio`, los controles y manejo general del reproductor funcionan bien. Quisiera de alguna formar precargar todas las músicas en el cachet del navegador a medida que escucha la actual.

En resumen, dispongo de:

```
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
var urls = [...track1.mp3, track2.mp3, track3.mp3];

btn_next.on("click", function(){
   audio.src = urls[index_next];
};

btn_prev.on("click", function(){
   audio.src = urls[index_prev];
};
```

¿Cómo precargar el audio de las demas URLs sin acción del usuario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigando un poco más acerca del asunto que comentas, he encontrado este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060642/preload-multiple-audio-files) en el foro stackoverflow inglés, espero que te ayude, ya que es exactamente lo que necesitas.

Espero que te sirva de utilidad.